# BibLaTeX: different name order for author/editor

Tags: biblatex

I would like to sort the names of authors and editors differntly in my citations. Authors should be listed as `LastName, FirstName` and editors as `FirstName LastName`.

So far I've tried this, but it hast only changed all names to `LastName, FirstName`:

```
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{first-last}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}
\DeclareNameAlias{editor}{sortname}
```

Comment: This depends on the style you use, so we would need to know more about that. Also do you want different formats even if the editor appears instead of the author at the head of an entry?

Comment: I have got the following BibLaTeX settings `\usepackage[backend=biber,style=verbose-ibid]{biblatex}`. If the editor appears instead of the author, the name should show just as the author's would: `LastName, FirstName`. Basically every and any name before the title should be set as `LastName, FirstName`.

Comment: Ahhh, that was more or less what I expected and makes perfect sense. I*'m slightly confused though because if I have `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}` with `verbose-ibid` in the *bibliography* I get exactly what you want, while in citations the authors are also "first-last". Are you thus asking about citations only?

Comment: Yes, sorry about the confusion! I am asking about this behaviour showing in both my bibliography _and_ cites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just the line

```
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
```

gives you almost what you want.

`biblatex` prefers the order "first last" in citations though and will go through quite some length to achieve this (it adds a `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}` here and there).
To prevent this, go with

```
\renewbibmacro*{cite:full}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:full:citepages}%
  \printtext[bibhypertarget]{%
    \usedriver{}
      {\thefield{entrytype}}}%
  \usebibmacro{shorthandintro}}
```

If you also want to keep `\fullcites` in line, you will need

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\fullcite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usedriver{}
     {\thefield{entrytype}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\footfullcite}[\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usedriver{}
     {\thefield{entrytype}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

as well.

As a bonus, the following will also make `labelnames` "last, first"

```
\DeclareNameFormat{labelname}{%
  \ifcase\value{uniquename}%
    \usebibmacro{name:last}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}%
  \or
    \ifuseprefix
      {\usebibmacro{name:last-first}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#8}}
      {\usebibmacro{name:last-first}{#1}{#4}{#6}{#8}}%
  \or
    \usebibmacro{name:last-first}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}%
  \fi
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=verbose-ibid]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:full}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:full:citepages}%
  \printtext[bibhypertarget]{%
    \usedriver{}
      {\thefield{entrytype}}}%
  \usebibmacro{shorthandintro}}


\DeclareNameFormat{labelname}{%
  \ifcase\value{uniquename}%
    \usebibmacro{name:last}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}%
  \or
    \ifuseprefix
      {\usebibmacro{name:last-first}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#8}}
      {\usebibmacro{name:last-first}{#1}{#4}{#6}{#8}}%
  \or
    \usebibmacro{name:last-first}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}%
  \fi
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}


\begin{document}
\cite{worman,geer,cicero,gaonkar,gaonkar:in,jaffe,baez/article}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]